# Multiple WTForms on same page, validation issues causing data in db to be set to NULL;

Tags: html, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm building a Flask web application, I have a page (route) that allows the user to edit their profile. I've built multiple bootstrap 4 cards that contain each form. I can get the form data to load just fine, though when it comes to submitting any of the forms below the first one on that page, validation becomes wonky, and sometimes will nullify data in other form data fields. (Epic Right?!)

I'm fairly new to python and flask and I believe that it may be the way I have the route configured in routes.py or the way that I'm doing form validation... I'm looking for guidance on how to better handle this problem.

One of the first issues I ran into when trying to use multiple wtforms on the same page is that the form id was the same across all forms, to counter this I used a tip found about specifying {{ form.csrf_token }} instead of {{ form.hidden_name }} and then specifying the form ID in the html template. This got things working, until I came across the bug where some form.data would be emptied and then submitted to the db.

Example: I could update my Education information and then submit the change, it then would wipe out my Work Place information...

edit_user_profile template: (

```html
   <form method="POST", id="AccountForm">
    ## Account Form Fields
   <button class='...' type='submit' form='AccountForm'>Update Account</button>
   </form>
...
   <form method="POST", id="ProfileForm">
    ## Profile Form Fields                
   <button class='...' type='submit' form='ProfileForm'>Update Profile</button>
   </form>
...
   <form method="POST", id="EmploymentForm">
    ## Employment Form Fields                 
   <button class='...' type='submit' form='EmploymentForm'>Update Employment</button>
    </form>
...
   <form method="POST", id="EducationForm">
    ## Education Form Fields
   <button class='...' type='submit' form='EducationForm'>Update Education</button>
   </form>
...
   <form method="POST", id="RelationshipForm">
    ## Relationship Form Fields
   <button class='...' type='submit' form='RelationshipForm'>Update Relationship</button>
   </form>
```

Routes.py

```py
@app.route('/edit_user_profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
...
def edit_user_profile():
    ## Define All User Forms
    ... removed to keep post smaller ...
    ##
    if AccountForm.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.username = AccountForm.username.data
        current_user.email = AccountForm.email.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Account Updated.', category='success')
        return redirect(url_for('user', username=current_user.username))

    if ProfileForm.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.firstname = ProfileForm.firstname.data
        current_user.lastname = ProfileForm.lastname.data
        current_user.nickname = ProfileForm.nickname.data
        current_user.bio = ProfileForm.bio.data
        current_user.gender = ProfileForm.gender.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Profile Updated.', category='success')
        return redirect(url_for('user', username=current_user.username))

    if EmploymentForm.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.work_place = EmploymentForm.work_place.data
        current_user.work_title = EmploymentForm.work_title.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Employment Updated.', category='success')
        return redirect(url_for('user', username=current_user.username))

    if EducationForm.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.school = EducationForm.school.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Education Updated.', category='success')
        return redirect(url_for('user', username=current_user.username))

    if RelationshipForm.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.relationship = RelationshipForm.relationship.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Relationship Updated.', category='success')
        return redirect(url_for('user', username=current_user.username))

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        AccountForm.username.data = current_user.username
        AccountForm.email.data = current_user.email
        ProfileForm.firstname.data = current_user.firstname
        ProfileForm.lastname.data = current_user.lastname
        ProfileForm.nickname.data = current_user.nickname
        ProfileForm.bio.data = current_user.bio
        ProfileForm.gender.data = current_user.gender
        EmploymentForm.work_place.data = current_user.work_place
        EmploymentForm.work_title.data = current_user.work_title
        EducationForm.school.data = current_user.school
        RelationshipForm.relationship.data = current_user.relationship
    ## Render Page & Forms
    return render_template('edit_user_profile.html', title='Edit Profile', ## various forms= various forms...)
```

Sorry for all the code dumps above, I tried to remove any irrelevant data. Also remember, I'm very new to python... so be gentle.

The way I understand this code is that each form has an ID associated it, as well as a matching button to post that form data. Form data will go through the validation determined in the forms.py (not included, as it is basic stuff, and I feel the issue is my route.)

Lets say I update my education information in the EducationForm, it will nullify data in EmploymentForm and still submit it for some reason.

When debugging, I can see that the POST data contains all the valid data, but then the odd bug occurs. I can tell that the post passes validation because I do get the flash of 'DB Updated' on submit.

Ideas or Suggestions? Let me know if you need any other code snippets. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be operating on form object instances. E.g. `educationForm = EducationForm(); educationForm.validate_on_submit()` You also don't need the elif, since if your code gets into any of the ifs, it will return.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Nick, I'll tamper with that configuration and report back!